# Piping a PowerShell DataTable to Export-Excel giving unwanted columns

Tags: powershell

This probably is obvious but since i'm a Powershell novice and use it for some ERP tasks, i'm having problems.  Yesterday, i downloaded Powershell 5 and Export-Excel cmdlet and it works, just better than i expected.  This command

$MoDataTable | Export-Excel -Path c:\temp\MoData.xlsx –Show -BoldTopRow -AutoSize

includes columns for RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, and HasError that are not germane to the data and would confuse anybody using the workbook.  The DataTable is populated from a dataset generated by an ODBC call.

So, after much searching and trying things, i’m giving up and turning to you wise experts.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `select-object` statement to select those rows, you want to Export.

Example with row1, row2 and row3:

```
 $MoDataTable | select-object row1, row3, row3 | Export-Excel -Path c:\temp\MoData.xlsx –Show -BoldTopRow -AutoSize
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark as answer, if it solved your problem, so others could benefit too.